# Increase gap in bar graph using code or property

Tags: vb.net, charts

I am creating a bar graph in vb.net and i need gaps between 2 bar. I need to increase gap in bar graph using code or property

[image]

And I also need to want to know how can I make that big integer of thousand and million values to k and M respectively.
eg  9899 to ?  it is simple for 1000 to 1k

Comment: Post code please

Comment: which code you need

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xNr-L7ILEmk&t=13s refer this for code